# Spring MVC Controller to handle more than one URL request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am developing XML configuration based spring MVC web application, so i plan to create a controller to handle more than one URL request, how can I create?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What code have you written>

Comment: The number of URL's is known, or you need it for an unlimited URL's?

Comment: I have tried each and every request for independent controller

Comment: I edited my answer - added variant for unlimited url's

Answer (score 1):

Annotation `@RequestMapping`  can take an array for its `value` parameter.

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/first", "/second", "/third"})
    public ResponseEntity<String> doSmth() {
// do something
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

You also can make `@RequestMapping(value={"/something/*"})` which will handle anything after `/something/`